# How to execute or implement batch file in java project with eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Is it possible to implement or extract batch file in eclipse and debug java project in debug mode. Because without batch file I can't debugging my project and can't set breakpoint.Or some another solution. How to debug my application with use .bat file to start my java project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to implement or extract batch file in eclipse and debug java project in debug mode.

Hmm... You can do everything you do with a batch file (assuming you're using it to start a Java program of course) from Eclipse with a **Run > Run Configuration...** (also available from the contextual menu after a **right-click** or via the top toolbar).

> Because without batch file I can't debugging my project and can't set breakpoint.

Why?! I don't think this is true.

> Or some another solution.

Start your class/project in debug mode using **Run > Debug** (reusing or creating a new **Run > Debug Configuration...**). Again, this is also available from the contextual menu after a **right-click** or via the top toolbar.

> How to debug my application with use .bat file to start my java project.

To be fully exhaustive, you can run an external program from Eclipse using an **Run > External Tools > External Tools Configuration...**. And you could indeed use [remote debugging options](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/conninv.html#Invocation) and connect a remote debugger from Eclipse. But honestly, I don't think you need that.

Maybe you should explain what you're trying to do more precisely.

Comment: When I start in debug mode I get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException in the main class which get args[] argument. And after when I insert one value for args[] I get a couple of exception from another class. Because is not only one batch file but it is too big project. And i have problems to complete all in eclipse.

Comment: @Gogoo When you create a *Configuration*, you can set program arguments in the *Arguments* tab. Not sure I can be more precise with the current details.

Answer (score 0):

Try remote debugging. Eclipse can attach to remote Java processes, but the Java program must be started with special keys. I don't remember them, google/help for your service.